# How to delete specific values from matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have image matrix 420x700, and I want to delete a specific value in each row, changing the image dimensions. It is like deleting a column from it, but not in a straight line, to become 420x699 image. I should keep the values before the deleted value horizontally and shift all the values after it back by 1 position.

```
RGB = imread('image.jpg');
I1 = RGB(:,:,1);
```

How do I do that?

Comment: For each row `r` in the image, store the row in a temporary array, delete the desired element, then copy the modified array to the output image at row `r`.

Comment: I think you do that exactly like you describe: for each row, move the values after your chosen index back by 1 position. Then you’ll be able to delete the last column.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question, and I cannot think of a way to do this without a for-loop.

Let `M` be the `nr-by-nc` matrix from which you want to remove a column, and `R` the `nr-by-1` vector with the column index of the element to be remove on each row.

The following code creates a new matrix `A` with the "column" removed from `M`, and vector `B` with the elements that were removed:

```matlab
    [nr,nc] = size(M);
    A = zeros(nr,nc-1,'like',M);
    B = zeros(nr,1,'like',M);
    
    for k = 1:nr
        r = R(k);
        t = [ 1:r-1, r+1:nc ];
        
        A(k,:) = M(k,t);
        B(k) = M(k,r);
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

@beaker and @Cris are correct, but just to add some flavor to this, I've attempted to demonstrate an alternate method - using linear indexing, which can teach an interesting lesson on column major indexing of 2D arrays in MATLAB.

Another point to note is that this kind of process is what's followed in the seam carving algorithm, where we remove a vertical seam in this manner.

Load a test image to run this on - crop it to analyze easier.

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
I = I(100:100+9, 100:100+19, :);

figure, imshow(I)
```

Create a mask indicating which pixels are to be removed. This simulates the condition which I think you're pointing to - in this case, we choose random column indices for each row to be removed. You'd likely have this information as an input.

```
mask = zeros(size(I, [1:2]), 'logical');
for idx = 1:size(mask, 1)
    randidx = randi(size(mask, 2));
    mask(idx, randidx) = 1;
end

figure, imshow(mask)
```

Use the column major linear indexing trick to do the removal faster! Since we're removing a column at at time, we rotate the image 90 degrees, and translate this problem to removing one row at a time. MATLAB indexes 'vertically', and so we can then use linear indexing to simply remove the masked pixels all at once (rather than one row/column at a time), and then restore the shape using reshape, and finally rotate back to the original orientation.

```
It = rot90(I);
maskt = rot90(mask);

% Preallocate output
Ioutput = zeros([size(I, 1), size(I, 2) - 1, size(I, 3)], 'like', I);

for nchannel = 1:3
    Icropped = It(:, :, nchannel);
    % MATLAB indexes column wise - so, we can use linear indexing to make
    % this computation simpler!
    Icropped = Icropped(maskt(:) == 0);
    Icropped = reshape(Icropped, [size(maskt, 1) - 1, size(maskt, 2)]);
    % Restore the correct orientation after removing element!
    Icropped = rot90(Icropped, 3);
    Ioutput(:, :, nchannel) = Icropped;
end

figure, imshow(Ioutput)
```

I've cropped the 'peppers' image to demonstrate this, so that you can convince yourself that this is doing it right. This method should work similarly for larger images as well.

Comment: I don't think this is right. You should transpose instead of using `rot90`, and the cost of doing that twice (before and after) far outweighs the cost of iterating across rows for large matrices, so this approach is actually slower than using a for-loop.

Comment: @JonathanH - I've manually tested the rotation idea - since the deletion of a pixel in a column is independent of other columns, rotation should be identical to transpose here. We only really need the 'orientation' to be 'vertical'.

I haven't done rigorous performance testing, so you are likely correct w.r.t. the traditional approach being faster. I've hence edited/removed the performance claims in the answer here. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: Thank you for proposing an interesting way of avoiding for-loops in this case! It's quite ingenious, even though it might not be the most efficient way. :)